# how to optimize C++ program to run MPI?

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, mpi

I have create this program to do Distance Proximity Analysis from foodbanks.dat and residences.dat it work fine in console but I want help to be able to run in on MPI.
Just how can vector to C array because in MPI will not accept C++ vector also how to  make each block of operation(read file and populate the vectors,calculate the distance to get the closet foodback andAnalysis the range in KM ) into separate functions

Comment: If using a C++11 `std::vector vec;` you could use [vec.data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to access to some array pointer, and feed that to *MPI* routines.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch even without C++11 you can use feed `&vec[0]` to the mpi function routines but i'll be using `vec.data()` going foward

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` uses an array internally, so all you have to do is get a hold of that array.

If you have C++11 you can use [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get a pointer to the array inside the of the `std::vector`.

If you don't have C++11 you can always use [std::vector::front](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) like so `&front()` to get the pointer to the array.

Just make sure that when you are doing this that you don't increase the size of the array inside the vector after getting the pointer because that will invalidate your pointer.

Code example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVec;
    myVec.push_back(0);
    myVec.push_back(1);

    //int* myArrayPointer = myVec.data(); // For C++11
    int* myArrayPointer = &myVec.front(); // For pre-C++11

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << myArrayPointer[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper Okay, I gave you a second option for when you don't have C++11.